# Ruby on rails Heroku deployment issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems

I am completely new to ruby on rails and heroku. I deployed my first ruby on rails app to heroku and when I go to the website it says Application error.

**Heroku Logs:**

```
2018-10-29T00:40:38.462970+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-10-29T00:40:43.768770+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 43245 -e production`
2018-10-29T00:40:47.367294+00:00 app[web.1]: Ignoring bootsnap-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.3.2
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927710+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize': Could not find nokogiri-1.8.5 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927736+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `map!'
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927740+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `materialize'
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927742+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs'
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927744+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:218:in `specs_for'
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927745+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:207:in `requested_specs'
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927748+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:109:in `block in definition_method'
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927750+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:21:in `setup'
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927752+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927753+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927756+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927758+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927759+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927762+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927764+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
2018-10-29T00:40:47.927767+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
2018-10-29T00:40:48.028594+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-10-29T00:40:48.011732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: We don't require your entire log file.  Please provide the pertinent section.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: Well see I don't know what I should be looking for. I might remove a section of the log that might be causing the issue.

Comment: Will the Heroku deployment build logs help any?

Comment: The logs says `Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.3.2`

Comment: Try running that on your local machine and update your Gemfile.lock. Push the updates and deploy.

Comment: the cause might be you did not include `nokogiri` in your Gemfile, please check this and try `gem install nokogiri -v 1.8.5` in your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

go to the folder where your app exists then do the following:

```
gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.3.2
bundle install
```

then try pushing to heroku again